# USA TD visa refused for 214(b) - new UK visa application

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa, refusal

I am a Canadian citizen (**also hold a Bangladeshi passport - dual citizen**), currently working in USA with my TN status. Since my wife is a bangladeshi citizen (we married recently), she applied for TD visa from Bangladesh, however she was rejected. So I found that TD visa is not very known in US embassy at Bangladesh (since TD/TN is for canadians/mexicans), so they refused on the ground of 214(b). I have never heard of a TD visa refusals but those applications were made in Canada, may be that is the difference.

Now there is a new situation. I am moving to UK now and applied for **Tier 5 Govt Authorized Exchange work visa** for 2 years duration. I got the visa and now my wife will apply for visa as a dependent of mine (we plan to arrive to uk on the same day (I from usa and she for Bangladesh) ). I am confused while filling out her visa application for UK. It is asking for the information that if she was ever refused for any country in last 10 years. I have a feeling that answering it ‘yes’ may reduce the chance of her UK visa (since US visa was refused due to lack of tie to her home country which does not make any sense though ). Answering it ‘no’ will be a lie but will increase the chances of visa it seems. Can someone plz suggest w

the problem is to convince that my wife has non immigrant intent and will not stay in uk after visa is over. for usa, the officer was not convinced abt her tie to home country since i can go back to canada but she cant as a bangladeshi citizen

**note that we are newly married (6 months) and her canadian immigration is in process but will take longer.**

Comment: I'll repost my comment from the closed question you posted to travel.SE: "Do not lie. There is a good chance they will know about the visa refusal because the US and UK share such information. If they uncover the lie, your chances are essentially *zero*. On the other hand, if you disclose the visa refusal and explain it, the UK officers will likely understand that the refusal was a bit screwy, and not hold it against your wife."

Comment: Since I wrote that, I've looked at the law and the regs, and they do require nonimmigrant intent, oddly.  I suspect that this is taken very lightly in practice, and the Bangladeshi consulate may not have been aware of that because, as you note, they probably don't process a lot of NAFTA visas.  Just have a strong application and perhaps include a short sentence or two explaining the circumstances.  If you're really worried about it, find a solicitor to help.

Comment: Do you have a right to live in Bangladesh, and if so when did you last live there? If you have no home in Bangladesh and have been living in Canada until recently, but your wife has no status in Canada and could not return there with you, then I fear you may have some issues convincing anyone that she has no immigrant intent and/or retains ties elsewhere. You must reveal the TD refusal to the UK (they'll likely know anyway), but even if this didn't happen the set of facts that lead to the TD refusal may cause similar issues with the UK. A lawyer might be worth it in this situation.

Comment: @Dennis, Fair point. But I'm not sure what other options they have to live together as husband and wife.

Comment: @ouflak what's wrong with Canada?

Comment: @litteadv, Only the small fact that he is not going to be there. I suppose she could go there and wait for him, although I don't know how necessary Canada would make it that her citizen spouse actually be present in their country she is attempting to immigrate to.

Comment: @ouflak if I'm a US/British visa officer, why would you think that I'd care? Clearly the wife has no intentions to go to Bangladesh, and she has no readily available residency elsewhere. Why would I approve a visa? I wouldn't. This whole situation is a bit bizarre (they're married, but don't live together? The husband keeps trying to get dependent visas for her to various countries?) and I'm not at all surprised that the VOs are skeptical.

Comment: @littleadv, Well, playing devil's advocate here, the situation is that they are married and trying to live together. They would be doing so now if the TD visa had been approved. So it's not like it's a situation that a border agent hasn't come across before. Many newly married couples of mixed nationalities face just exactly these kind of issues all the time, including couples where one of the pair is a UK citizen. They aren't heartless robots. Further, the UK is actually fairly accommodating to genuinely married couples to some degree (as opposed to say boyfriend/girlfriend arrangements).

Comment: @littleadv, If I'm the border agent, and I see that they are genuine and that he meets all of the support requirements, I probably let them in on the balance of things.